# Eject key no longer working

Tags: keyboard, eject

The <kbd>Eject</kbd> key on my iMac (OSX Lion) is no longer working. It was working fine until a few days back, and I remember sleeping my display using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> shortcut, when I first found out about the shortcut, a few days back. But it is no longer working.

- I have checked that it is not set as the shortcut for 'Speak selected text' option
- I have tried resetting the NVRAM
- I have tried switching user to check if it is a software problem

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried with other keyboard?

Comment: I don't have another keyboard with eject key.

Comment: Have you check if the Mac can detect key presses from the eject key using the keyboard viewer?  System Preferences > check Show Keyboard. In the Input Sources list make sure Keyboard & Character Viewer is checked.  Then go the menubar and click on the keyboard drop down and select Show Keyboard view, and see if the eject key is working there.

Comment: The "eject" key is really just F12. Attach another keyboard and press F12 and see if it works.

Comment: @MrDaniel - I had already tried that. The Eject key is not present in the Keyboard Viewer. I checked on my Macbook too, and it is not present there either.

Comment: @MichaelStern Thanks for that info. I'll check that and report back.

Comment: @MrDaniel - I could not find another USB keyboard for testing. But I tried connecting the wireless keyboard to my MacBook, and the Eject key did not work there too. Does Apple care warranty extend for Apple Wireless Keyboard too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem you should try to see if the problem is hardware or software.

We are going to rule out software because of the hardware testing that was completed.

As noted in OP's comment

> ... But I tried connecting the wireless keyboard to my MacBook, and the Eject key did not work there too ...

Since this problem persisted across multiple macs that strongly points to a hardware issue with the eject key on that Apple wireless keyboard.

If your Mac that the keyboard came with still has some coverage under AppleCare then Apple should cover repairing or replacing the keyboard according to  [AppleCare - Mac and Apple Display Coverage](http://www.apple.com/support/products/mac.html)

> What’s covered — Mac
>
> - Your Mac computer
> - **Included accessories** such as the power adapter

Comment: Thanks for the help MrDaniels. I couldn't find a usb keyboard today to test with the iMac. I'll test it with the F12 key tomorrow and report back. Do I have to take the iMac along with the keyboard, if I want to avail the warranty?

Comment: I would think that it would not be necessary to bring in the iMac, maybe just provide the serial number for it and bring in the defective keyboard, but I would call Apple First and see what they say you should do before making a trip.